# A note of appreciation to the moderators for making challenging, controversial questions work

Tags: discussion

Moderating can be a thankless task, so I thought I'd drop a quick note of thanks for doing a good job of it here.

I've seen a lot of questions on Workplace.SE that touch on sensitive and controversial subjects, which some moderators would just freak out at and close, lock and/or delete. The Workplace mods and regulars have, however, for the most part, done a very good job of making sure difficult topics are addressed with high quality content (while firefighting the inevitable arguments and dross).

[You can probably guess which question prompted me to post this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/54020/how-to-politely-say-i-dont-want-to-work-for-someone-from-xy-country)  - but there have been plenty like that. I must admit I was a little skeptical when the Workplace was launched that it could work - and I'm very happy you've done a good job proving me wrong.

Feel free to close this since it isn't exactly a question... `:-)` tagging "discussion".

Comment: As one of the close-voters of that same question on ELL, I'm pleasantly surprised that it got such a good reception (and solid answers) over here. Well done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you.  We humans tend to mostly speak up when we're *un*happy, so it's great to hear positive feedback too!

Most of the moderation on this site comes from the community, as it should.  You're the ones who decide on scope, close and reopen questions, edit posts, leave helpful comments, use our chat room, and bring issues to meta constructively.  This site wouldn't work without y'all doing all that, so thank you.

Answer (score 8):

I agree.  This site tends to get personal for a lot of us and we know that we abuse you and make you feel unloved at times.  Know that you are loved even when we are disagreeing with your position. I can not understate how impressed I am with our mods willingness to step in and just purge comments, delete trouble answers, and generally do your best to herd us like cats into areas where we are providing help instead of arguing.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 5):

Since I'm only a newly minted moderator (where did that first month go? :) ), I feel like I'm taking credit for the more experienced people who have been looking after the community for far longer than I have been here.  But on behalf of the mod team, thank you :)

I feel it is truly an honour to be an ambassador for the community, but much of the moderation is done by you all, the members *of* the community.  I believe we as moderators are doing our job well if most of the time you don't really notice us at all :)

Comment: You've done great... I remember voting for you a month ago :)

Comment: @eyoung100 LOL, thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

Well, as moderators we've all pondered what to respond to this and aren't really sure how... I guess I'll just say, thank you - we all enjoy the work.

It's fun to be part of a site which can literally impact people's lives.

Also, we have a really great community here. Thank you (and everyone else) who help make Workplace such a great place. I think this site has definitely surprised a lot of people overall and not being what they expected it'd be (expectations were.. low for the Workplace working out).